# Calculate total Amount Paid on Prepare Payments

Tags: acumatica

Good day
Page: AP503000 
Build 19.104.0024

I am trying to calculate the Total Amount paid for all recorded in the APAdjust grid on the bottom of the Prepare Payments. This total I want to show on top in the Form area.

DAC

```
namespace PX.Objects.AP
{
    public class PayBillsFilterExt : PXCacheExtension<PX.Objects.AP.PayBillsFilter>
    {
        #region UsrTotalAmountForPayment
        [PXDecimal]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Total Amount For Payment")]
        public virtual Decimal? UsrTotalAmountForPayment { get; set; }
        public abstract class usrTotalAmountForPayment : 
        PX.Data.BQL.BqlDecimal.Field<usrTotalAmountForPayment> { }
        #endregion
     }
}
```

My first attempt I tried to add an unbound formula to my DAC for the below to work you will also need to add a new class decimal_0

```
namespace PX.Objects.AP
{
    public class PayBillsFilterExt : PXCacheExtension<PX.Objects.AP.PayBillsFilter>
    {
        #region UsrTotalAmountForPayment
        [PXDecimal]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Total Amount For Payment")]
        // add this to the DAC
        [PXUnboundFormula(typeof(Where<APAdjust.curyAdjdAmt,Greater<decimal_0>>)
        ,typeof(SumCalc<APAdjust.curyAdjdAmt>))]
        public virtual Decimal? UsrTotalAmountForPayment { get; set; }
        public abstract class usrTotalAmountForPayment : 
        PX.Data.BQL.BqlDecimal.Field<usrTotalAmountForPayment> { }
        #endregion

        //Class decimal_0 
        public class decimal_0 : Constant<decimal>
        {
            public decimal_0()
            : base(0)
             { }
        }

     }
}
```

I have also tried adding an event to do the calculation:

```
namespace PX.Objects.AP
{
  public class APPayBills_Extension : PXGraphExtension<APPayBills>
  {
     #region Event Handlers
     protected void APAdjust_RowInserted(PXCache cache, PXRowInsertedEventArgs e)
     {
        var row = (APAdjust)e.Row;
        PayBillsFilter filter = this.Base.Filter.Current;
        PayBillsFilterExt FilExt = PXCache<PayBillsFilter>.GetExtension<PayBillsFilterExt>(filter);

        if (filter != null)
        {
            FilExt.UsrTotalAmountForPayment += row.CuryAdjdAmt;

        }
      }   
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For accurate results I recommend you sum all the records at the same time.
You can use the `DataView.Select` method to iterate all records.

```
public void PayBillsFilter_UsrTotalAmountForPayment_FieldSelecting(PXCache sender, PXFieldSelectingEventArgs e)
{
    decimal total = 0;

    foreach (APAdjust adjustment in this.Base.APDocumentList.Select())
    {
        total += (adjustment.CuryAdjdAmt != null ? adjustment.CuryAdjdAmt.Value : 0M);
    }

    e.ReturnValue = total;
}
```